# Do cooks in the US measure volume using 'traditional' or 'legal' units?

Tags: measurements

The wikipedia article for the [cup unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cup_%28unit%29) identifies two different measures used in the US: a *[legal](http://www.fda.gov/Food/GuidanceComplianceRegulatoryInformation/GuidanceDocuments/FoodLabelingNutrition/ucm063102.htm)* cup of 240ml and a *[customary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_customary_units)* cup of ~236.588ml.

Similarly, the [tablespoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tablespoon) and [teaspoon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaspoon) articles describe *traditional* measures (~14.8ml and ~4.93ml respectively) and measures used in "nutritional labeling" (15ml and 5ml).

Are measuring spoons in the US calibrated to the *traditional*, or to the *legal* definitions of these units?

Comment: both.  (within acceptable tolerances, as I doubt they're that well calibrated, or that usage is that precise)

Comment: In case it seems odd that I would need to known this; I'm doing calculations based on a large number of recipes and I want to introduce as little systematic bias as possible.

Comment: Then you likely need to look at when and where the recipes were created & tested, and how/if the 'legal' definitions made it into general (non-commercial) usage.

Comment: To put things into comparison -- during my undergrad (civil engineering), there were lots of different ways to calculate the strength of a steel-reinforced concrete beam, with results that varied somewhere on the order of 5% of each other ... my professor showed that if you consider that the accuracy of steel placement is within 1" in many cases, that threw the strength by ~20%.  So, my point is -- how someone fills the cup is likely of more signficance than which of the two sizes of cups they use.  (especially for flour ... but then you also have regional differences in production).

Comment: @Joe You're right of course. I was rather hoping that I could simply rule out the legal units since I nevertheless have to settle on a default measure when the exact unit isn't indicated (which is the case for most recipes). How someone fills the cup is, as you say, of greater significance. I'm just going for the low hanging fruit to begin with, and this question seemed like it may have an answer.

Comment: Unless it's coming from a recipe to be used in bulk commercial processing, I doubt they would use the 'legal' measures.  My only other suggestion might be to try contacting the various ['test kitchens'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betty_Crocker_Kitchens), and ask them what they use.  Among other things, the commercial test kitchens verify that cookbooks recipes work as listed, and so they might have to deal with this issue.

Comment: If the market for measuring instruments is quasi-monopolic, you can just measure which the market leader uses, because this will be the one most cooks use, no matter who created the recipe.

Comment: Many of us use a 20 year old set of chrome plated measuring cups, with all their dents, and distortions from the round. Plastic measures are also popular, but stuff sticks to the cheap ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Great question Chris!  I'm a US baker who has been baking for a LONG time and never gave it any thought whether my measuring utensils are "legal" or "traditional" - they say "1 cup", "1 Tsp", "1 TBSP", etc.

In practice, all this has meant to me is that when my US recipes call for 1 cup of flour, I measure 1 level measuring cup of flour.  Same for teaspoons and tablespoons.  My European cookbooks refer to ingredients in weight (250 grams, for example).  In those cases, I would either convert those measurements into my more familiar cups, tsp's, TBSP's, etc., or use another set of utensils with measurements marked on the side.

While I've used the written measurements for a guideline, I've always also depended on the preparation instructions to determine the correct consistency of the dough or batter.  This is particularly true for flour and liquids.

Regarding uniformity in the measurement tools, unfortunately for the home cook, there is no one monopoly.  Every grocery store, dollar store and cooking store has an assortment of measuring cups and spoons.  Some of the better measuring cups, like those from Pyrex, have volumes written on the side of the cup to use as guides.

Answer (score 9):

I took a look at some measuring cups and spoons available via amazon. For the vast majority, there is no information available regarding either the exact measure or the intended market (cup measures differ as much as 44ml between english speaking countries). Nevertheless, there are a few products where the milliliter conversion is provided.

To begin with some good news; every one of 20 measuring spoon sets used a 15ml measure for the tablespoon and 5ml for the teaspoon. This was the case even for brands that sold a traditional US cup measure.

The situation is a bit more messy for cups. Out of 20 cup measure sets, 6 products used the *legal* cup, 8 used the *traditional* cup and 6 were *metric* cup measures (250ml). It's doubtful that US consumers would knowingly purchase the 250ml cups. Remember though that most cups available online don't specify their exact volume, so it is possible that a meaningful percentage of online US consumers are unwittingly measuring in metric cups. Some angry comments in the amazon product reviews appear to confirm this.

It was clearly nonsensical to mention calibration in the question. Apart from the anecdotal evidence indicating the inaccuracy of measuring cups, I also note that the specified milliliter conversion for *traditional* measures ranged from 235ml to 237ml. The one measuring cup I saw claiming to be "precision engineered for accurate measurement" didn't even indicate whether it was for measuring a US cup.

My conclusion is that *traditional*, *legal* and *metric* cup measures are used in the US although I would expect the proportion of *metric* cups available in the shops to be much reduced to what I saw online.

Comment: I wouldn't be confident the teaspoons and tablespoons were all actually 5 and 15 mL; they may just be rounding. The same might even happen for cups.

Answer (score 5):

What a great discussion. I don't think there is really an answer regarding whether most US cooks use "legal" or "customary" cups as I don't think that most cooks know that there is a difference. A legal cup is only 1.44% larger than a customary cup. This is a very small difference. I'm willing to bet that if a cook measured a cup of flour 10 different times with the same measuring cup that his results of each measurement would vary far more than 1.44%.

My other thought is that if a cook always uses the same set of cups, be they customary, legal, or metric, then their recipes would always turn out because all ingredients would be proportioned the same.

My answer to this problem is to throw away your measuring cups and start using a scale!

Answer (score 1):

I’m a cook but also a trained engineer, a former math and science teacher and a practicing optician. Who cares, right? But let me explain why it’s relevant here.

First, as an educator, your question makes me proud because we emphasize precision and accuracy in the classroom. The comments about using a scale are very sound math and science. So is the comment about ratios—a foundation of good cooking. As an engineer, I’m deeply familiar with the realities of the rubber meeting the road. Even the most precise instruments don’t account for user biases. Thus, we allow tolerances or allowable errors and make allowances for this by design.

If industrial precision and consistency are your goal, having well know, and accurate measuring tools is required and an analytical balance (scale) is the standard. As an optician I refer to an ANSI standard to pass or fail eyeglasses based on fairly loose tolerances.

My cooking experience falls in line with these. Human beings mostly tolerate 10% sensory variations with ease. Those who don’t are unusual and difficult or even impossible to please. The bottom line is that it probably doesn’t matter UNLESS you are packaging something professionally/commercially/medically in which case...USE A SCALE!  Bon appetit

Comment: Good point on the optical issues -- I doubt most people know which liquids are supposed to measured via the top or bottom of the meniscus.  (I've also questioned the accuracy of the printing on some liquid measuring cups).  But if you make something more than once, you can make notes about how to vary the recipe for your measuring tools, so it'll come out better the next time